# SQL interfaces error 0X89C50118

Tags: windows-10

I made a adminstration project with Visual studio 2015 and a sql database file mdf, the Sql server is from 2016. In my pc1(windows 10 enviroment) which I created this project , the first rebuiled release is woking nice without any problems. But this application with the database needs do work at a another pc2 (window 10 enviroment). so I installed the release at this pc2 with the required databases and Sql server 2016 (with same sql server configuraion as pc1). In  pc2 includs also the SSMS(V18.4) which was also installed in pc1 to creade a *mdf database.

The problem is when I start the apllication at pc2, somehow it can not connect to the database, while every thing is set it up as pc1 besides(username , pc name). Af the 30sec timeframe  get a message which is coming from my try and catch code(see picture below)

[image: SQL interfaces error 0X89C50118]

The configuration of the connection strings of the application looks like picture below which is similar the first picture

[image: Connection config]

The things which I have checked is

- In PC2 With SSMS I have attached the required mdf files and the SSMS with out any problems
  I can enter the database with the SSMS and see already the data which was filled in with my new
  application

-Checked the settings in SQL SERVER Configuration manager and this should be ok because the settings
is similar as pc1

-The security of the folders(database and application) is set for everybody(full user rights).

-The necessary service for the sql is running

After all these checks still I get this SQL interface error and it drives me up to the ceiling.

Does somebody have some suggestion about this interface error?

Comment: Don't post pictures, post readable text.  "every thing is set it up as pc1 besides(username , pc name)"  What is the name of PC1?  Do you see it in the PC2 connection config?

Comment: The name of pc1 is "PCboven" and pc2 is "DEKTOP-S2THM3" but in the config there is no any name of the pc mentioned

Comment: It is normal for a configuration where the connection is to a DB on the same system: no need to mention the name of that system. But a remote connection - to another system - is impossible without identification of the remote system.  Would you mind reading an article like: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server/ ?

Comment: thank you for this aticlke , i will read it but I need to inform there is no remote coonection in this case because i will install the same release and db on pc2 , I keep in touch

Comment: I do not use this remote connection , so what i did is I backuped the related database from pc1 and restored this at pc2 buunotunally the error remains....

Comment: I thought PC2 had to use the database on PC1.  Did you define the datasource on PC2?  Did you install SQLLocalDB.msi?

Comment: yes i have defined the folder  for the database, inluding the databas which backup frompc1 and recoverd at pc2 with ssms  , and i can edit with ssms which also installed at pc2 just for testing, yes I have installed  SQLLocalDB from the "SQL server installation center 2016"

Comment: "I do not use this remote connection "  The error message says "Controleer of ... externe verbindingen zijn toegestaan".  SQL Server says you're trying to make a remote connection.  Who am I to believe, Den Boesterd or Den Server?

Comment: Mr Gerard!You need to trust me instead of windows, As I said pc1 is also working with this  localdb without remote connection, anyhow did the same install today in an other win 10 machine (pc3)there  it is working, so I believe something is messed up in the sql side at pc2

Comment: Sorry Ferry, I always trust the computer. Why does PC2 think kim_s_uren.Form4 needs a connection to a remote database? Which datasource is used on line 5268?

Comment: I found the issue!, PC3 it is running with localdb pefect, conclusion sql messed up at pc2 , found out that ODBC driver 13 was missing but could not install because higher odbc version was active, so deinstalled ODBC driver 17 but it seems there are some remans from 17 that blocks to install 13, bug which is also known in some forums

Comment: Perhaps a complete reinstall of PC2?

Comment: Yes when I get the opportunity , I will do that , keep in touch